# Hadoop MapReduce ClassNotFoundException Error

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, hdfs

I have extracted a jar from a Maven project that runs the MapReduce job. However, I keep receiving the error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException". The things that I have tried to use to repair this is:

- Configured the classpath
- Tried doing job.setJar(.jar)
- Attempted job.setJarbyClass(.class)
- Changing JobConf path file
- Caress Hadoop and tell it everything is going to be okay

I extracted the jar file from Maven and transferred it to a Linux server, and running it from there. 
The full error message is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BLAMapAttempt2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

If there is any missing information needed to answer this question, please let me know, and thank you for reading.

Comment: Is  BLAMapAttempt2 in the jar?

Comment: Yes it is in the jar. --- I've extracted the jar to check.

Comment: If it is of any help, the command i use to execute this is
        hadoop jar BLAMapAttempt2.jar BLAMapAttempt2 {inputfolder} {outputfolder}

Comment: Are your linux permissions for that jar set correctly?

Comment: Chmod'ed the file to 777, and still receiving the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When exporting the jar out of Eclipse, I unchecked "classpath" because I was not running it locally. This fixed my error.